# ElectronJS Vue Axios Basic Authentication Access-Control-Allow-Origin error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors, electron, axios

I have been googling the all of the interwebs and I just can't find the solution to my problem. I'm trying to make an application using ElectronJS and I need to send an HTTP request with authentication basic header but I just can't get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
export default {
    name: 'home',

    data: function() {
        return {token: ''}
    },

    methods: {
        fetchData() {

            this.$http({
                method: 'get',
                url: 'URL_TO_SERVER',

                auth: {
                    username: 'USERNAME',
                    password: 'PASSWORD'
                },
                headers: {
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    credentials: 'same-origin',
                },
                withCredentials: true,
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log('ERROR: '+ error.response.data);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load (URL_TO_SERVER). Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Does anyone have any idea's what could be my next step to fixing this?

If i do the same info with a REST client it will return the correct values, just not in ElectronJS

Answer (score 0):

After building the application in to an EXE, it worked, just doesnt work in npm run dev.